# phantomjs - Status=Success , No Response Data

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am trying to make a Screenshot of a Website, trying with multiple URLs and always with a same empty response of WebData- But the response is always "Success" in the Debug Modus.
The Callback function of "page.open" doesnt print any status. The Only output is "exit" like i defined it in the last line. Please see my Code:

```
    var system = require('system');
    var args = system.args;

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

    page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 720 };
    var urlAddress = 'http://phantomjs.org/'.toLowerCase();

    page.open(urlAddress, function(status) {
        if ( 'success' !== status ) {
        console.log('Unable to load the url address!');
    }else{
        console.log('got it');
        page.render("1.jpg", { format: "jpeg" , quality: '90'}); 

    }

    });
    console.log('exit');
phantom.exit();




Request {
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "text/html,application/...
        },
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0"
        }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "method": "GET",
    "time": "2....",
    "url": "http://phantomjs.org/"
}
Receive {
    "contentType": null,
    "headers": [],
    "id": 1,
    "redirectURL": null,
    "stage": "end",
    "status": null,
    "statusText": null,
    "time": "2019-...",
    "url": "http://phantomjs.org/"
}
```

I already deacitvate the Firewall and tried different web sites with the same result.

Since I reinstalled my Windows 10 this happened